# JQuery post data and file upload and get result as JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

HTML :

```
<input id="myId" type="text">
<input id="newFile" type="file" name="newFile" >
<input type="button" onclick="sendData()" value="Send" >
```

JQuery:

```
function sendData() {
    var id = $("#myId").val();
    var myFile = $("#newFile").val();
    $.post("test.php", { id: id , file: myFile  },function (data) {
        console.log(data);
     }, "json").fail(function (data) {
        alert("error");
    });
}
```

this code post id value and the file name !!
i want to post file ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: you could use https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-submit-additional-form-data jquery plugin

Answer (score -1):

to upload file with AJAX, try this:

```
var formData = new FormData();

var cpt = 0;

$("input[type=file]").each(function () {
    $.each(this.files, function (i, file) {
        formData.append("file" + cpt++, file);
    });
});

$.ajax({
    url : "serveur.php",
    type : "POST",
    data : formData,
    processData : false, 
    contentType : false, 
    dataType : "json",
})
.done(function (reponse) {

});
```